# Speeding up solving equation with symbolic expression

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve an equation using a symbolic (`syms`) expression, then evaluating it expression using `eval`. The program is working fine, but it takes a long time. I know using `syms` decreases the speed, is there any way that I can speed up the process? I was wondering about using a function to put the symbolic expression inside it then calling this function. I do not know if that would help or how to do it though. Any other suggestions are very appreciated.

I used the below code

```
clear;
clc;
syms A B C D E ; 
R=((4*B*A)/((D-C)^2+(B+A)^2));
R1=((4*B*A)/((D+C)^2+(B+A)^2));
F1 = ellipticK(R);
I1 = ellipticE(R);
F2 = ellipticK(R1);
I2 = ellipticE(R1);
P= ((((A*B)^(1/2))/(2*E*(R^(1/2))))*(((2 - R)*F1) -...
    (2*I1)))-(((((A*B)^(1/2))/(2*E*(R1^(1/2)))))* ...
    (((2 - R1)*F2) - (2*I2)));
P1=feval(symengine,'simplify',P,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');

X=(1/B)*(diff(P1,D));
X1=feval(symengine,'simplify',X,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints');
M(:)=0;
for i=1:10000
    A=L1(i);B=L2(i);C=L3(i);D=L4(i);E=L5(i);
    M(i) = (eval(X1))*0.13; 
end
```

Comment: What do you think you're achieving when doing `A=A(i);...` in the loop? `A` isn't defined as a matrix anyway so not sure what `A(i)` is, and then even if it was you destroy it by doing the assignment?

Comment: @Wolfie. Thank you. This is part of the code. I got them from L1, L2, L3, L4, and L5 which are 1-D matrices. I update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your problem first to a function handle using [`matlabFunction`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) as follows:

```
F = matlabFunction(X1);
M = F(L1, L2, L3, L4, L5)*0.13;
```

This makes your code ~100x faster.

Note that you can also export your function to a script file, using the [`'File'` argument](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#input_argument_d0e105357):

```
matlabFunction(f,'File','myFunction.m')
```